# (решено) почему не передаются перменные в функцию array_map php?

Tags: php

Есть срочки в коде (читайте комментарии в коде):

```
<?php
logFile($domen_crm.' / '.$apikey_crm.' / '.$code_magazine.PHP_EOL);
// тут 3 переменные есть и выводятся.
$prod_mass = array_map( function($v){
    return [
        'quantity'=>$v['quantity'],
        'offer' => [
            'id' => logFile($v['name'].' / '.$domen_crm.' / '.$apikey_crm)
        ]
    ];
}, $json); // тут выводится только перменная $v['name'], а $domen_crm и apikey_crm пустые.
```

Первый раз такое вижу. Видимо я плохо знаю работу array_map

Comment: ох, вы бы знали как тяжело читать такой код...

Comment: Прошу прощения, если не трудно, вставьте в свой notepad с разметкой

Comment: Откуда им взяться-то? Вы их в функцию передали? Нет.

Comment: Просить прощения здесь не надо. Надо сразу публиковать __читаемый код__.

Comment: Здесь даже ссылка [edit] есть, если вы не заметили.

Comment: Не нужно писать в заголовке "решено", для этого существует галочка возле ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в области видимости переменных для анонимны функций https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php.

`array_map` в вашем случае принимает аргумент анонимную функцию.

Достаточно добавить `use ($domen_crm)` на:

```
$prod_mass= array_map(function($v) use ($domen_crm, $apikey_crm) {
    return ['quantity'=>$v['quantity']...
```

и всё заработает.

Comment: вот тоже читал про это, только использовал неверно:
logFile(null,$v['name'].' / '.use($domen_crm).use($apikey_crm))

Comment: блин, я конечно понимаю что вам не очень важно то, как вы отправите код, но пожалейте тех, кому нужен этот ответ.

Comment: @КонстантинСоколов, если бы я был заинтересован в вопросе, я бы занялся им. но в данный момент мне интереснее разбирать форматирование, и я этим и занимаюсь

Comment: @КонстантинСоколов, правильные ответы следует отмечать галочкой около вопроса, чтобы участникам ресурса было понятно, помог ли вам этот ответ или нет